# Google Calendar API how to get Reminders set from google keep, goals, appointments and tasks

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to get all these things from google calendar online. As of now, the only things I can get are the list of calendars and the events. Is there anyway I could get these information or tell them apart?

Comment: check this link you can get all params from google calendar >> https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/

Comment: Vipin, which ones of are the reminder, appointment and goal? there is a reminder parameter but it seems like it is literally how the user is reminded.

Comment: anything new in 2019?